# navbar is not fixed when visiting page with a hash value e.g (example.com#footer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a jQuery to change the navbar from static to fixed by adding `.navbar-fixed-top` to navbar element after scrolling, it works fine.

but when visiting a part of the page with a URL HASH, `.navbar-fixed-top` is not added to the navbar.

e.g it works fine when you visit the page **without hash**:
https://codepen.io/ExillustX/pen/jmQpyo

**with hash** navbar is not fixed: https://codepen.io/ExillustX/pen/jmQpyo#footer

so my question is how can i make the navbar fixed when page is visited with a hash url?

any help is appreciated.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 550) {
      //                        $("#navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
      $("#navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");

    } else {
      $("#navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
      //                       

    }
  })
})
```

```css
#home,
#content,
#footer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#home {
  background-color: #ff3366;
}

#content {
  background-color: #78519a;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #c80032;
}

.navbar-brand h2 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <h4>nav ;/</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="home">
</div>
<h4>Navbar toggle</h4>
<div id="content">

</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this just before the end of the ready function:

```
$(window).trigger("scroll");
```